# Incorrect syntax near 'Word, Another Word'

Tags: sql-server

I'm at a loss on what to do. I'm trying to fix an old broken query that was messing something up. If I use the database2 script, it populates what I want. However, when used with the Update, it gives the syntax error.

```
USE Database
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[tblParts]
SET [Database].[dbo].[tblParts].[Cost2] = StdCost
FROM (SELECT [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName], [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[CustomField2] AS StdCost
FROM [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory]
INNER JOIN
[Database2].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail] ON [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[ListID] = [Database2].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[IDKEY]
INNER JOIN [Database].[dbo].[tblParts] ON [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName] like [Database].[dbo].[tblParts].[PartNo]
WHERE ([Database2].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[AccountRef_FullName] = 'Word, Another Word'))
```

error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'Word, Another Word'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a derived table, but didn't give it a name. So, after you final closing parentheses, you need to alias this derived table.

Also, I don't know why you are doing the following, but didn't change them. I just found it odd.

- Returning the FullName column since you aren't using it
- Self joining to Database2
- Using `Like` without `%`

Here's the updated query with a comment at the bottom

```
USE Database
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[tblParts]
SET [Database].[dbo].[tblParts].[Cost2] = StdCost
FROM (  SELECT 
            [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName], 
            [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[CustomField2] AS StdCost
        FROM 
            [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory]
        INNER JOIN
            [Database2].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail] ON [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[ListID] = [Database2].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[IDKEY]
        INNER JOIN 
            [Database].[dbo].[tblParts] ON [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory].[FullName] like [Database].[dbo].[tblParts].[PartNo]
        WHERE 
        ([Database2].[dbo].[salesorpurchasedetail].[AccountRef_FullName] = 'Word, Another Word')
    ) as SomeName   --name it here
```

I think you could simplify it as:

```
UPDATE D
SET D.[Cost2] = D2.StdCost
FROM 
    [Database] D
    INNER JOIN
    [Database2].[dbo].[itemnoninventory] D2 ON
     D.[PartNo] like '%' + D2.[FullName] + '%'
WHERE
    D2.[AccountRef_FullName] = 'Word, Another Word'
```

Comment: odd comment: I'm just trying to make it work right again without changing much. That stuff was there since creation.

Comment: To make it clear: I created a new column to test this so that the normal column is not changed. Well, the query runs, but changes all the values to the same result.If I run the select, it gives them all as expected.

Comment: added this and seems to give what I expect:   ) AS SomeName
WHERE SomeName.[FullName] = [Database].[dbo].[tblParts].[PartNo]